# Scriptmethod responseformat set to JSON returning XML

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-3.5

I have the follwing method

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<MyObject> GetMyObjects()
    {
        return Business.GetMyObjects();
    }
```

as you can see the web method is set to **JSON** but the method is returning **XML**

I am using the following **JavaScript** to access this web method.

```
function getMyObjects() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/treenode/myobjects.asmx/GetMyObjects",
    dataType: "JSON"
}).success(function(data) {
    var response = data.d;
    alert(d.param);
});
}
```

This may well be a quick fix but I am missing something and cant see what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by adding an ajax option of

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
```

I overcame the error